# Converting dict containing objects to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tkinter

Lets consider a dictionary full of objects, defined in a below way for reasons:

```
for i in range(1, len(list_of_players)+1):
    d["test_player{0}".format(i)] = Player(i, list_of_players[i-1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Now, using tkinter I'm opening a root in which values of each player mentioned might be changed. Next, I'd like to convert those values to DataFrame to then export them to Excel. Doing below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d.items())
print(df)
```

prints only each objects ID which is to be expected, but I have no clue how to reasonably access actual values. I'm aware that I could switch that to a list using something like below:

```
d_list = []
for i in range(1, len(list_of_players)+1):
    d_list.append([d["test_player{0}".format(i)].name, 
    d["test_player{0}".format(i)].goals, 
    d["test_player{0}".format(i)].assists])
```

and then convert that list to a DataFrame, although I don't believe there is no cleaner way to approach that. Could you please advice how to convert the "d" dictionaries values directly into DataFrame?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)`, where `list_of_rows` is a list of dict-like opjects (that is, `dict` or `pd.Series` that will be interpereted as rows, which can itself be built with list comprehension:

```
list_of_rows = [{'name': d[player].name,
                 'goals': d[player].goals,
                 'assists': d[player].assists} for player in d]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, although thats what I did (in slightly different manner). I'm wondering if I can go directly from a defined dict in a mentioned way above to a dataframe